# Building on Laravel API backend and Vuejs frontend

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-router, vuex

I would require a little help here if this method will work out well.

Firstly, I have a backend API server created using `Laravel` and `Laravel Passport`. Secondly, I have also created the frontend with Vuejs within the same project. As such, I will be required to use both the `api.php` and `web.php` routes. I am also redirecting these routes using `vue-router`.

---

### Backend

Inside the `web.php` routes, I have used two different routes because I want to display generic contents on my landing site and the other as an authentication required dashboard.

#### Example:

`web.php`

[image: web.php]

As above, this is to capture the routes which are `404 Not Found` that are directly manipulated in the address bar to redirect correctly to their respective pages. I also ended up having two different blade templates named as `dashboard.blade.php` and `home.blade.php` respectively. Is this an okay practice for a Laravel-Vuejs project? Or are there ways that you would like to recommend?

`dashboard.blade.php`

[image: dashboard.blade.php]

`home.blade.php`

[image: home.blade.php]

---

#### Login related problem with login page using the layout of the landing page into another layout of the dashboard page

The problem that I am faced with when doing an API login with the password grant is that the login page does not redirect to the dashboard page properly. The URL route does change but the page is rendered as blank.

The login using `axios` here:

[image]

Comment: If you are having `VueJS` then why don't you use `Vuejs-router` for redirecting the pages?

Comment: @NitishKumar, my apologies. Yes, I am using `vue-router` and `vuex` for my routing and authentication. I am in fact, redirecting pages using my `vue-router` routes. I have also used `axios` for the ajax requests. The problem is a successful login will redirect to a blank page that is on another layout blade template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to fix the problem.

In `web.php`, since we have

```
Route::get('/dashboard/{any?}', function () {
    return view('dashboard');
})->where('any', '^(?!.*api).*$[\/\w\.-]*');
```

Inside of my `Login.vue` redirect handler, I use `location.href = '/dashboard'` instead of `this.$router.push('dashboard')`.